# Xpath to get Background-image attribute in DIV

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

What can be the Xpath to get the background-image CSS Property of a DIV tag whose ID is mentioned in (selenium webdriver)?

Ex: (div id="abc", style="width: 538px !important; height: 242px !important; background-image: url(http://test.com/images/abc.png); position: relative; background-position: 0% 0%;")

I want to find this image with url:(http://test.com/images/abc.png)

Answer (score 15):

I don't get your question, please format and expand a bit, it's kind of vague to me.

I assume you want to ask one of the following questions, but not sure which.

- How to get the `background-image` CSS Property of a `div` using Selenium?

**Answer:** Use Selenium's native `GetCssValue()` (C#), `css_value` (Ruby), or equivalent method in other language bindings.

```
IWebElement abc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='abc']")); // use XPath as you requested
string imageUrl = abc.GetCssValue("background-image");
```

- How to locate a `div` element by its `background-image` CSS property using XPath?

**Answer:** If you don't want to use ID (which you should in this example case), you can totally do it in CssSelector or XPath. (XPath is the last option you should choose though)

```
IWebElement abc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@style, 'background-image: url(http://test.com/images/abc.png);')]"));
```

- How to use XPath to get an element's attribute content which has `background-image`?

**Answer:** Not really useful for Selenium, but here you have it: `//div[@id='abc']/@style`

Comment: I think he wants to get the image itself not the url